# How can I disable the value tooltip on a Vaadin-Charts/Highcharts SolidGauge chart?

Tags: highcharts, vaadin, vaadin-charts

How can I get rid of this popup/tooltip that says "Wait Time: 3.1"?

Here is my setup code for the Data Labels and Plot options

```
        this.series = new ListSeries("Wait Time", 0);
        final PlotOptionsGauge plotOptions = new PlotOptionsGauge();
        plotOptions.setTooltip(null);
        series.setPlotOptions(plotOptions);
        final DataLabels dataLabels = new DataLabels();
        dataLabels.setEnabled(false);
        plotOptions.setDataLabels(dataLabels);
        configuration.setSeries(series);
```

There does not appear to be a setter that disables this tooltip.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The answer is you have to disable it at the chart configurations not the series configurations

```
                final Configuration configuration = gaugeChart.getConfiguration();
                configuration.getChart().setType(ChartType.GAUGE);
                configuration.getChart().setPlotBackgroundColor(null);
                configuration.getChart().setPlotBackgroundImage(null);
                configuration.getChart().setPlotBorderWidth(0);
                configuration.getChart().setPlotShadow(false);
                configuration.setTitle("");

                /* This line removes the tooltip */
                configuration.getTooltip().setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: That sounds about right. null in Vaadin Charts most often means that go with the default settings. When you call `plotOptions.setTooltip(null);` it will then use standard behavior, which has the tooltip visible.